# Visual Studio Code can't be opened because "Apple cannot check it for malicious software"

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I have downloaded Visual Studio Code for the first time but I keep getting message below:

[image: apple error message when clicking on VSC app]

> "Visual Studio Code" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
>
> This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.

My MacBook is up to date, and I even updated the latest version of VSC on their website (September 2019 (version 1.39); there is none for October) but it still gave me the same message.

Looking into their FAQ, I read about reinstalling VS Code. I did that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Note to close voters: take another look at the part in the close reason where it says "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Comment: Q1 2020: This is fixed for the next VSCode 1.43, as documented in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592247/6309).

Answer (score 323, accepted):

macOS Catalina requires apps to be notarized by Apple. Your version of Visual Studio Code is yet to be updated by Microsoft for the new OS.

Please try the following:

> **Right-click on the app and select *Open*.**

If this did not work, remove the quarantine extended attribute that’s set on the app:

1. Move the app to the Applications folder
2. Open Terminal.app, then paste and execute the following command:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app`

Comment: Straight away this didn't work for me however after executing this command I needed to explicitly double click on VSCode application.

Answer (score 51):

If `Right Click` > `Open` doesn't open Visual Studio Code:

Another alternative can be simply navigating to `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy`.

In the `General` tab, navigate and click `Open Anyway` button next to *("Visual Studio Code" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified source)*.

[Security & Privacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Xyl.png)

Comment: Changing `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` option once is more convenient than using CLI `xattr` each time. Thank you!

Comment: This approach fixed the problem for me on my new Mac book pro 16

Comment: THIS IS MUCH THE BEST ANSWER. When right-click->Open fails, this action is exactly the authorization you want using the exact MacOS operation for the problem. You should not use `xattr` commands whose effects may not tie in to the overall security system.

Comment: this is the right way of doing it :) more user friendly....

Answer (score 6):

The official issue for this is [microsoft/vscode issue 74782 "Investigate: macOS notarization"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74782)

But, [as noted in January 2020 iteration](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87479#issuecomment-570299327) for VSCode 1.42:

> Extremely disappointed to see that #74782 won't be fixed until early February.

(it was supposed to be [possibly done for January](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74782#issuecomment-567353275))

> First it was supposed to be fixed in November, then in December, and now it slips all the way to February.
>   This, for a feature (app notarization) first announced in 2018, for an operating system (Catalina) that has been available in beta for > six months and which went Gold in October, and which anyone who has purchased a new Mac since has no choice but to run.
>
> Yes, I realize there is a workaround to install on macOS Catalina, but I don't want to install a non-hardened app. Every other app I've needed / wanted to install on my new Mac was hardened and notarized on a timely basis.

Edit: **Feb. 2020**, now that VSCode 1.42 has been released, [vscode commit c196df9](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c196df9d3ac60fde7f8c37b8bd4cac6a52ab98f8) from [**João Moreno**](https://github.com/joaomoreno) is supposed to solve this issue; from [PR 86588](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/86588).
[João adds](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74782#issuecomment-583374527):

> Starting next week, insider builds should be properly notarized. ✔️

("insider builds" for the next 1.43 version)

[VSCode 1.43](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/91f29764466853ee1e7fe029713a6038465e8ac9/release-notes/v1_43.md#notarized-macos-builds) does mention:

> ### Notarized macOS Builds
>
> Visual Studio Code for macOS is finally notarized, so you should no longer see the following dialog:
>
> [image: Notarization]
>
> Read the [investigation issue](http://Notarized%20macOS%20Builds%20%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20for%20macOS%20is%20finally%20notarized,%20so%20you%20should%20no%20longer%20see%20the%20following%20dialog:%20%20Notarization%20%20Read%20the%20investigation%20issue%20and%20Apple's%20developer%20documentation%20for%20more%20details.) and [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution) for more details.

Comment: According to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/86588, "The signing service currently has an issue, so the app bundle comes back broken. We're waiting on a fix from their side."

Comment: @MarcDurdin OK, thank you. That would explain the delay.

Comment: @MarcDurdin PR 86588 just got merged to master.

Comment: insiders is fixed, but waiting for the main release

Answer (score 0):

In my case non of the above worked.

I simply deleted vscode from my applications folder ('move to trash') and [reinstall](https://code.visualstudio.com/download). worked like magic!
When I opened vscode all my work was still there :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking solution for mac Ventura then open the terminal and `type sudo spctl --master-disable`.
Hit enter and provide the Mac password.
Now go to your **privacy & security**, scroll down, and there you will see the option of anywhere in the security menu. Select **anywhere** and thats it.