# How to work around this error message on iOS Catalina (10.15.1)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, download, installation, macos-catalina

When trying to install, I receive the following:

“Visual Studio Code” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a programming forum. Your question is not regarding programming, you should ask at [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Code can't be opened because "Apple cannot check it for malicious software"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457958/visual-studio-code-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious)

Here is the solution, the following was working for me:

*navigate to System Preferences > Security & Privacy.
In the General tab, navigate and click Open Anyway button next to ("Visual Studio Code" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified source).*

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in v1.43, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#notarized-macos-builds

> Visual Studio Code for macOS is finally notarized, so you should no
>   longer see the following dialog: