# Unable to install VS Code for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded VS Code for Mac, but I'm unable to install it on my MacBook.  I get the following error:

> "Visual Studio Code - Insiders" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Here is a sreen shot of the full error message:

[image: Startup Error Message]

**How can I get VS Code to install and run?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using or installing apps on macOS/Apple. There is another Stack Exchange site that's more appropriate for this: [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There's a related Q&A with the same error: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so

Comment: To be fixed in v1.43, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676779/how-to-work-around-this-error-message-on-ios-catalina-10-15-1/60456411#60456411 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#notarized-macos-builds

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by macOS requiring apps to be notarized by Apple. The best way around this problem is to simply right-click on the app and select Open. If this doesnt work, first move the app to the Applications folder. Then open Terminal and paste and execute the following command:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app`

This should remove the quarantine on the app and allow you to run it.