# VS code problems

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have downloaded the zip file for **macOS** from the vs website. I moved the `.app` file to the application folder.

However, when I try to start the app by clicking on the icon. The app doesn't open. I have searched on the internet but the only problem I see people having is about *privacy settings*. And my problem is not related to that. I see that the VsCode is starting to launch at the top of my monitor I see "code" at the top but only for 2 seconds.

Comment: Try this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_vs-code-is-blank
Does it change anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install VS Code for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314178/unable-to-install-vs-code-for-mac)

Comment: It is not the same problem because it doesn't give me any problem message, that is also why I can't fix it myself