# Problem Running Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: macos, security

When I download Visual Studio Code for my MacBook Pro (running the latest version of MacOS, 10.15.1), I get a message:

“Visual Studio Code.app” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Is there a way around this, or is the app being updated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code can't be opened because "Apple cannot check it for malicious software"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457958/visual-studio-code-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious)

Answer (score 0):

This is a security mechanism from your operating system. If you trust the app, you can right klick on the file and open it from the context menu. Then you have to confirm again that you want to open it and it should work as expected.