# Latest Visual Studio Code Build Won't Run on OS X Catalina 10.15

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

Downloaded latest build of Visual Studio Code 1.41 and get"

> **“Visual Studio Code 2.app” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.**
>   This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code can't be opened because "Apple cannot check it for malicious software"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457958/visual-studio-code-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to install VSC,  go into the Security & Privacy look at the bottom and it should ask if you want to go ahead and install.
HTH